# Can't install Pillow with PIP 3.10

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install Pillow library in PIP, but it is not working
I am installing Pillow for Tkinter, but it is not working.

Here is what it is showing (I have tried --user, and I have latest PIP version)

Here is what it says

```
Collecting pillow
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/0a/f8/f4a5e9c5f35fbb2e3bfd9b9596d0937e8242ae14ae4172da12dd770c7bdc/Pillow-9.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/0a/f8/f4a5e9c5f35fbb2e3bfd9b9596d0937e8242ae14ae4172da12dd770c7bdc/Pillow-9.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/0a/f8/f4a5e9c5f35fbb2e3bfd9b9596d0937e8242ae14ae4172da12dd770c7bdc/Pillow-9.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/0a/f8/f4a5e9c5f35fbb2e3bfd9b9596d0937e8242ae14ae4172da12dd770c7bdc/Pillow-9.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/0a/f8/f4a5e9c5f35fbb2e3bfd9b9596d0937e8242ae14ae4172da12dd770c7bdc/Pillow-9.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/0a/f8/f4a5e9c5f35fbb2e3bfd9b9596d0937e8242ae14ae4172da12dd770c7bdc/Pillow-9.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I need to install pillow.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any post as text, not images.

Comment: Download the required package directly from pypi.org and install the downloaded package using `pip`.

Comment: If you are downloading from a corporate network, you are likely to need to configure your proxy (pip.ini file in %APPDATA%/pip folder on windows, which is your os according to the snippet provided): https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#configuration

Comment: For pc. sudo pip install pillow --upgrade For linux, sudo pip3 install pillow --upgrade